# Does Xcode Has Keyboard ShortCut for going back and forth in programming?

Tags: xcode

In xcode you can go back and forth in your program by swiping the mouse.

Is there an additional keyboard shortcut for that?

In visual studio 2010, for example, you do so by Ctrl - and Ctrl Shift -

How do you that in xcode with the keyboard?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. The keys in Visual Studio 2010 that you refer to (for others that are unaware) are known as "Navigate Backward" and "Navigate Forward" and work as described in the the following [Microsoft Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20140903060333/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/vseditor/archive/2009/09/22/searching-and-navigating-code-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx) allowing you to quickly move back and forward between places you’ve already been in your code, via a "Jump to Definiton" in Xcode, for example.

The equivalent keyboard shortcuts in Xcode 4 are:

Navigate Backward:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Left Cursor</kbd>

Navigate Forward:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>Right Cursor</kbd>

Comment: How do you make that cool ⌘ sign anyway?

Comment: @JimThio Personally, I just use the Character Viewer and drag them in from there. You can enable it on the menubar by checking System Preferences -> Keyboard -> "Show Keyboard & Character Viewers in menu bar". There are also some good tips on using the keyboard characters in [this meta answer](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/683/put-the-characters-somewhere-for-people-to-copy-paste)

Comment: I'm wondering why "Ctrl + Apple + Left Cursor" works for me when the menu button says the shortcut is "fn + Left Cursor".  Why does "fn" = "Ctrl + Apple" instead of just being the "fn" key?

Comment: @Marty Where are you seeing this? Under the "Navigate" menu in Xcode, on my Macbook, the "Go Back" and "Go Forward" menu items have shortcuts as I've described.

Comment: Yeah under the navigate menu.  It says "fn + Left" and "fn + left", but that just jumps to the beginning and end of the document.

Comment: These shortcuts for Xcode navigate to the previous/next file but not cursor location which is the better option and which is what Visual Studio does with Ctrl + -/+. Can someone tell how to navigate to the previous/next cursor location?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd>? This switches you between applications. It is similar to <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>tab</kbd> in Windows. You can also press <kbd>⌘</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> to switch between windows in the same application.

Comment: Not really but +1 for effort.

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for this for so long time and what works for me is:

⌃ + 2 (Ctrl + 2 - Shows previous history) then click ↓ - this will jump back to previous definition

⌃ + 3 (Ctrl + 3 - Shows next history) then click ↓ - this will jump to next definition

This will only work if you navigate through your class using ⌃ + 6 to jump between definitions.